# How to draw a line that intersects a text node without seeing the line inside the node

Tags: css, javafx, drawing, intersection

I would like to draw a vertical line, and that vertical line may intersect a text object. When I do so without any modification, the line goes right through the word, making the word hard to read. I want to make it so that the line disappears when it reaches the text, and continues immediately after the text node. I've tried using toBack() with a css background for the text to make a square around it, but it seems like text nodes have transparent backgrounds, so the line is still visible behind the letters. Is there another way of doing this so that the text is not intersected by the line? Note that the text may or may not be there all the time, and it can be at any coordinate due to the nature of my program, so I can't just draw two lines (One before the text and one after).

Comment: Can you set the `Z-order`  or move the text object to the front?

Comment: Did you try making the `Text` object's background color the same as the `Parent`'s object background color?

Comment: Do you need to use a `Text`? If you can use a `Label` you can make the background opaque. Otherwise you can consider placing the `Text` in. e.g. a `StackPane` and give the `StackPane` a background color.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Yes I did both. It appears that the text object's background is transparent, so even if I moved it to front, the line is visible through the gaps between the letters because of the transparent nature of the background.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson `Text` doesn't have a background color, does it? It only has `fill` and `stroke` (it's a `Shape`), which color the interior and exterior of the individual glyphs, respectively.

Comment: You are going to have to put your `Text` object into a `StackPane`. The `StackPane` needs to be the same color as the backgound.

Comment: @James_D I will try that. Also, a follow up question: Can I set toFront() in the creation of the node but before I place it on the screen? I create all my shapes/labels in a separate object and then return an arrayList to the controller, which then adds them to the screen there. Can I call toFront in the initial creation in the object?

Comment: @James_D I just looked at `Text`'s properties using SceneBuilder and you are right.

Comment: `toFront` just moves a node to the front (i.e. to the end of the children list): see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront--). If you subsequently add something else to the end of the list, it won't be at the front any more, but of course you can always add a new node to any position in the child list that you need.

Comment: That clarifies a lot of things for me, thank you very much @James_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Label` instead of a `Text` will make things easier. `Label` is (ultimately) a subclass of `Region`, so it has properties such as a background color which can be styled, allowing it to have an opaque background. Using the CSS rule

```css
-fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
```

on a label will give it the default background color. By contrast, `Text` is a subclass of `Shape` and only has properties such as `fill` and `stroke`, which color the interior and exterior of the glyphs that make up the text, respectively.

So you can do

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextVsLabel extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane labelPane = new StackPane();
        labelPane.setMinSize(250, 250);

        Label label = new Label("A Label");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: -fx-background;");

        labelPane.getChildren().add(label);
        addLineToPane(labelPane);

        StackPane textPane = new StackPane();
        textPane.setMinSize(250, 250);
        textPane.getChildren().add(new Text("A Text"));
        addLineToPane(textPane);

        HBox root = new HBox(5, labelPane, textPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addLineToPane(Pane pane) {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.startXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        line.endXProperty().bind(line.startXProperty());
        line.setStartY(0);
        line.endYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());

        // add line to beginning of pane's parent list, so it appears
        // behind everything else
        pane.getChildren().add(0, line);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

which results in

[image]

Note that if you need more space around the text in the label, you can add padding to the label: `-fx-padding: 1em;`, etc.